# Updating my live project to python 3.10 - ERROR python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully

Tags: python, mysql, django

I've been having some trouble when trying to install certain packages on my live version of my project and realized its because its running version 3.7 instead of my up to date version 3.10 on Windows 10.
Wheels and setup are both up to date.

When I try to pip install -r requirements.txt I get a number of errors which I'm having no luck in fixing.

installing mysql seems to be the reason for these errors appearing.

ERROR1:
python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.

ERROR2:
Running setup.py install for mysqlclient did not run successfully.

ERROR3:
error: command '/opt/rh/gcc-toolset-9/root/bin/gcc' failed: No such file or directory
error: legacy-install-failure

Comment: [yum install gcc-toolset-9](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/developing_c_and_cpp_applications_in_rhel_8/additional-toolsets-for-development_developing-applications).

Comment: @danblack hey, thank you. I've seen this command multiple places and it doesn't work in my terminal.... I'm fairly new to coding so have no idea why this isn't working either is yum just for mac or something?

Comment: No hint of OS was in the question so I was going off the path to assume it was a RHEL install. Which exact package of mysql and version are you installing? Seems to depend on gcc in some-way and mysqlclient if that isn't installed. "don't work" is a very painful explanation of something incorrect. Be a programmer and be precise, what was observed vs what is the desired observation.

Comment: Okay, apologies for the lack of context, I will try better my self in this area. I'm running a Windows, python 3.10.7.  The mysql im trying to install is 2.1.1 I've also tried a few older versions with still no luck. I have also upgraded wheels and setup with no luck either. I have noticed that the webserver version of python is 3.10.4 and not 3.10.7 but from what I've read else where this should make no difference. Regarding the gcc it's definitely pointing towards an error here. @danblack

Comment: Checked back on my terminal on PC I have run the "pip install mysql-connector-python" which worked but the pip install mysqlclient==2.1.1 and over versions still returns error.